# Clang crashes on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows, crash, 64-bit, mingw, clang

I've been using clang successfully on Windows XP and Windows Vista using the 'experimental' builds for MinGW, but now that I try on my new Windows 7 64-bit laptop it simply crashes. Even if I just run "clang++" or "clang" it crashes, and I can't figure out how to get windows to give me more detailed crash info (I will edit that in if I can). I've redownloaded clang and reinstalled MinGW, and I've tried running clang.exe in compatibility mode, but it still doesn't work. This is the first time I am using it on 64-bit, I hope that's not the issue (if it is, I still have another computer I can use).

I've looked around and can't find anyone else having this same problem with clang crashing before even giving any output or processing any input, I really feel lost.

Comment: Why don't you answer the question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now happened multiple times on various system and I have found the solution. **Reinstall MinGW using the *prepackaged* files**, the 'latest' ones have a tendency to be unstable in relation to clang. Make sure you haven't also installed a newer version of gcc on top of the MinGW installation, as that will cause issues too.

Comment: You solved my problem with this! Thank you for taking the time to post the solution you found.

Comment: Yeah, it seems a lot of people are having trouble with the latest versions of MinGW and clang because the MinGW people renamed a bunch of DLLs that clang uses.